FFmpeg play file to DeckLink
I need to playback files to a DeckLink card using FFmpeg. For testing I'm using this file: https://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/big_buck_bunny_1080p_h264.mov
The file plays nicely using ffplay:
ffplay -i $FILE

I can also play it on my DeckLink card using Gstreamer:
gst-launch-1.0 \
  filesrc location="$FILE" ! tee ! queue ! \
  decodebin ! queue ! \
  videoscale ! videoconvert ! videorate ! \
  decklinkvideosink mode=1080p24 device-number=2

However when using FFmpeg:
ffmpeg \
    -re -i "$FILE" \
    -filter:v scale=1920:1080 -filter:v fps=24 \
    -an \
    -f decklink -format_code Hp24 -pix_fmt uyvy422 'DeckLink Quad (3)'

Then playback works during ~1.5s but fps drops and it quickly freezes. CPU load is low.
ffmpeg version 7.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --extra-cflags='-I/home/user/softwares/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-7.1/ffmpeg-7.1/include -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/home/user/sdks/blackmagic/Blackmagic-DeckLink-SDK-14.2/Linux/include/' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/user/softwares/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-7.1/ffmpeg-7.1/lib -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -L/home/user/sdks/blackmagic/Blackmagic-DeckLink-SDK-14.2/Linux/include/' --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-7.1 --bindir=/opt/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-7.1/bin --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-libs='-lpthread -lm' --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx265 --enable-nonfree --enable-nonfree --enable-decklink --enable-ffplay
  libavutil      59. 39.100 / 59. 39.100
  libavcodec     61. 19.100 / 61. 19.100
  libavformat    61.  7.100 / 61.  7.100
  libavdevice    61.  3.100 / 61.  3.100
  libavfilter    10.  4.100 / 10.  4.100
  libswscale      8.  3.100 /  8.  3.100
  libswresample   5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libpostproc    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'videos/big_buck_bunny_1080p_h264.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2008-05-27T18:40:35.000000Z
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.audio.gain: 1.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.audio.treble: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.audio.bass: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.audio.balance: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.audio.pitchshift: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.audio.mute: 
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.visual.brightness: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.visual.color: 1.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.visual.tint: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.visual.contrast: 1.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.version: 7.4.1 (14)
    com.apple.quicktime.version: 7.4.1 (14) 0x7418000 (Mac OS X, 10.5.2, 9C31)
    timecode        : 00:00:00:00
  Duration: 00:09:56.46, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 9725 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, 9282 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 2400 tbn (default)
      Metadata:
        creation_time   : 2008-05-27T18:40:35.000000Z
        handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
        vendor_id       : appl
        encoder         : H.264
      Side data:
        displaymatrix: rotation of -0.00 degrees
  Stream #0:1[0x2](eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
      Metadata:
        creation_time   : 2008-05-27T18:40:35.000000Z
        handler_name    : Time Code Media Handler
        timecode        : 00:00:00:00
  Stream #0:2[0x3](eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 437 kb/s (default)
      Metadata:
        creation_time   : 2008-05-27T18:40:35.000000Z
        handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
[vost#0:0/wrapped_avframe @ 0x651ff00f3bc0] Multiple -filter/-af/-vf options specified for stream 0, only the last option '-filter:v fps=24' will be used.
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> wrapped_avframe (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[decklink @ 0x651feffc5cc0] Found Decklink mode 1920 x 1080 with rate 24.00
Output #0, decklink, to 'DeckLink Quad (3)':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.audio.gain: 1.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.audio.treble: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.audio.bass: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.audio.balance: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.audio.pitchshift: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.audio.mute: 
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.visual.brightness: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.visual.color: 1.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.visual.tint: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.visual.contrast: 1.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.version: 7.4.1 (14)
    com.apple.quicktime.version: 7.4.1 (14) 0x7418000 (Mac OS X, 10.5.2, 9C31)
    encoder         : Lavf61.7.100
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: wrapped_avframe, uyvy422(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbn (default)
      Metadata:
        creation_time   : 2008-05-27T18:40:35.000000Z
        handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
        vendor_id       : appl
        encoder         : Lavc61.19.100 wrapped_avframe
frame=   25 fps=0.3 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:01.37 bitrate=N/A speed=0.0146x

I got the same behavior when using:

another card (a DeckLink 8K Pro)
an older FFmpeg version (4.4.3)
other files
a webcam

What am I doing wrong?
